# 404 error at API while logging the app from simulator

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created the simple login page in xamarin.forms,i have API for those logins,while running at postman iam getting the output,but while logging from the simulator iam getting the following error.

{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=639506ba4afdd530b4429c0d57e89977accb4b666a1e17dbe3fcc5c1fce369d5;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=snovahub.azurewebsites.net
Date: Wed, 13 Sep 2017 13:23:00 GMT
Content-Length: 3485
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}

My Api method is as follows:

```
#region Get results from api
    public static async Task<T> GetResultFromApi<T>(string serviceUrl,bool isTrue=true)
    {
        try
        {              
            GetConnection();

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(SnovaHubApiUrls.SnovaHubWebUrl + serviceUrl));

            var stringAsync = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseJson = stringAsync;

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseJson);
            }

            LoggingManager.Error("Received error response: " + stringAsync);
            return default(T);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LoggingManager.Error(exception);
            return default(T);
        }
    }
#endregion
```

Comment: What gets passed in for `serviceUrl`? Also, do you change the URL based on a DEBUG vs RELEASE build? Also, what does `GetConnection()` do?

Comment: @hvaughan3,email Id and password are the parameters passed through service url and
  private static void GetConnection()
        {
            if (_httpClient == null)
            {
                _httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(SnovaHubApiUrls.SnovaHubWebUrl) };
            }
        } for getting connetion this GetConnection().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the `HttpClient.BaseAddress` and then also passing in a full URL when calling `HttpClient.GetAsync()`. You need to choose one or the other. So:

Option 1:

```
private static void GetConnection() {
    if (_httpClient == null) {
         _httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(SnovaHubApiUrls.SnovaHubWebUrl) }; //You MUST place a / (slash) at the end of your BaseAddress ("http://something.com/api/" for example)
    }
}
```

Then in your `GetResultFromApi()` method:

```
...

var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(serviceUrl); //You MUST NOT place a slash at the beginning of 'serviceUrl' when using BaseAddress
```

Option 2:

```
private static void GetConnection() {
    if (_httpClient == null) {
         _httpClient = new HttpClient(); //Removed BaseAddress
    }
}
```

Then in your `GetResultFromApi()` method:

```
...

var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(SnovaHubApiUrls.SnovaHubWebUrl + serviceUrl)); //Passing full URL
```

Comment: Thanks for response@hvaughan3,i tried both the scenarios but none of them are succeeded, i am again getting the same error.

Comment: @sahithi Trying passing `http://www.bbc.com/` into `GetAsync()` and do not set the `BaseAddress`. This will prove that your code works and then it is probably either an issue with the URL that is being passed in or with your web service.

Comment: @hhvaughan3 After passing the `http://www.bbc.com/` i got response as status 200 but got exception `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value`

Comment: @sahithi Do not worry about the exception, the important thing is the 200. So look at exactly what URL is being used to make the request and make sure Postman is not sending any extra headers or anything.

Comment: @hhvaughan3,Thank you for spending lot time on this,finally i understood this is due to web service,after changing URL everything is fine.